# What's the difference between "Normal Reload", "Hard Reload", and "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

I recently discovered this new feature in Chrome:

[image: reload options]

I can figure out the difference between option 1 and option 3, and that option 2 is probably something in between, but I can't find any more precise information anywhere.

Does anybody know the precise behavior of each of the 3 options?

Comment: Could you explain "this feature"? Specifically: how do you access it? I tried all kinds of right-clicks, control-clicks, ... but couldn't get it. What version is this?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Haha that's my little secret... Seriously it's extremely well hidden: you have to press the refresh button without releasing it immediately *while the developer console is active* http://www.samuelrossille.com/home/blog-chrome-reload-options.html

Comment: I'd like to add that this only works if the console is open and docked.

Comment: What an incredibly wonderful tool.  Thank you for posting this.  I battle with coding, clearing and refreshing daily. I typically launch an incognito window for this but this is cleaner still.

Comment: Also appears by right-clicking the reload icon (while Devtools is open)

Comment: Does this work for OSX Chrome? I can't seem to get it open via Dev Tools and right click/click + hold

Comment: @nitsujri Yes, I works for me. I'm on Mac OS X 10.10 Chrome 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit)

Comment: I just found these features in year 2016 by accident...

Answer (score 517, accepted):

#### Normal reload

The same thing as pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. This will use the cache but revalidate everything during page load, looking for "304 Not Modified" responses. If the browser can avoid re-downloading cached JavaScript files, images, text files, etc. then it will.

---

#### Hard reload

Don't use anything in the cache when making the request. (which is equal to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> No need to open Developer console) Force the browser do re-download every JavaScript file, image, text file, etc.

---

#### Empty Cache and Hard Reload

Obviously, if the cache is empty then it will have to do a hard reload. This will again force the browser to re-download everything. However, if the page makes any after-the-fact downloads via JavaScript that weren't part of page load, then these might still use the cache, which is where emptying the cache helps because it makes sure that even these won't use cached files.

---

**Note**: This feature is only available when the developer tools are open.

Comment: Does anyone know if the third option just empties the cache for the current site, vs emptying the *entire* cache?

Comment: @Grinn: I don't, but I'd love to. You could ask that question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Grinn: Actually, now that I think of it, it's probably the entire cache. The point of that feature is to clear after-the-fact downloads, which aren't restricted to just one "site".

Comment: I'm unclear on what is considered an `"after-the-fact download via Javascript"`?  Can someone provide a concrete example?

Comment: @Costa You can download stuff that is not initially specified in the DOM. For example by adding a new <script> tag to your DOM, or by using RequireJS etc. Any AMD-based library (such as RequireJS) basically loads its scripts lazily. In that case, you have to empty the cache to make sure that really everything gets a hard reload.

Comment: @Grinn's question is important enough to ask as its own question (as suggested), so I've done so at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771569/does-empty-cache-and-hard-reload-empty-the-entire-cache-or-just-parts-relevant

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct anymore. Pressing F5 / Ctrl + R / Clicking on the reload button seems to force browser to check resources again and not use cache. The only way I can get it to actually use cache is to hit enter on the link address

Comment: It should be noted that this **only** works if the developer tools are open (F12) It would be nice if this was a setting that could always be available regardless if the dev tools are open or not.

Comment: When I hit F5 (normal reload) all the files are downloading from server but not from cache with request header 'Cache-Control:no-cache', what parameters should I set?

Comment: @scunliffe The shortcuts seem to work without the DevTools open (Normal Reload - Ctrl+R, Hard Reload - Ctrl + Shift + R)

Comment: @nbrooks The third option (empty and hard reload) is only available when the dev tools are open, and there's no keyboard shortcut

Comment: Is there way a user can add a keyboard shortcut to the third option?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer In dev tools, go to the Application tab, on the left, expand cookies and right click the domain(s) and click Clear, or select a domain and select the individual cookies on the right and press the delete key to remove them selectively.

Comment: I always used cmd+shift+r for had reload, but it doesn't seem to work anymore without the dev tools open. Anyone else find that?

Comment: Interestingly enough, Google's [developer site](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/hard-reload) explicitly mentions "With DevTools opened" (as of writing)

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos Here's an option: in settings -> click "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)". Then you don't even need a keyboard shortcut :)

Comment: Is it possible to automatically empty the cache when reloading the page if dev tools is already open? It's annoying to right click and select "Empty cache and hard reload" every time.

Comment: Do we have references to any publication by Google that may corroborate this?

Comment: I can't seem to verify that F5 or normal use of the Reload button in the toolbar causes request to be re-validated -- on my Chrome 86 all of my site's assets are served from cache _except_ the index HTML file for which at least a request is made with a 304 from server. Is this some optimization of Chrome? Why wouldn't it re-validate the rest of the things the HTML file references? The response headers in all cases are only `ETag` and `Last-Modified`.

Comment: Is there a difference between this and having `Disable cache` checked in the network tab when reloading?

Comment: In which of these three categories does the following procedure belong: "chrome://settings/clearBrowserData in URL -> "Cached images and files" is selected -> "Clear data" ?

Comment: What is the cache in this case? the local storage and cookies?

Comment: I'm still confused about Hard Reload and cached resources.  When I click Hard Reload it seems to load some things from the server (whether or not they are cached) and other things from the cache.  But I can't tell why some and not others.  And the things from the cache are always from disk cache not memory cache.

Comment: Can you explain "but revalidate everything during page load, looking for "304 Not Modified" responses"? Does this mean that if it doesn't find "Not Modified Responses" it will download them (isn't this equivalent to hard refresh)?

Answer (score 5):

This also works in Mac OS X. Open developer tools, and then, on the reload button, either
1. secondary click (right click for right-handed mouse), or
2. long click, aka long press
to see the menu.

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969509/1899424), hard reload often causes proxies, content delivery networks and other remote caches to be refreshed.

[image]

Comment: *“hard reload often causes proxies, content delivery networks and other remote caches to be refreshed.”* → Can you back it up? Do you have any citation explaining why this would be the case? I would expect the Hard Reload to just reload all local cache, and would have no additional effect on remote servers.

Comment: I think browsers send a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header. http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Force-cache-reload-for-object-from-browser-td1028329.html Does yours?

Comment: I did some testing… Going to the URL or using *Normal Reload* sent 3 cache-related headers: `Cache-Control: max-age=0`, `If-Modified-Since`, `If-None-Match`. However, doing *Hard Reload* (with or without emptying cache), only 2 cache-related headers were sent: `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache`. So, yeah, the browser indeed sends a header asking servers for a fresh version; it's then up to servers (including proxies) to change behavior based on that.

Comment: Great! You can edit that into my answer, or write your own answer. @DenilsonSáMaia

Answer (score 2):

The following method let you clear cache only for the troubled URL. It helped me when I was stuck with http to https redirection cache.

1. Open Chrome developer tools, in Windows I use `F12`
2. Check `Preserve log` to save the log before redirection
3. Right click the redirected URL and `Clear browser cache`

This will clear only the troubled cache without affecting normal cache.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reference to the spec - the browser performs one of these actions when a reload is triggered:

A 'normal reload' performs either a 'Specific end-to-end revalidation' or 'Unspecified end-to-end revalidation', as defined by the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9), i.e. cache is used, but revalidation occurs, either with a cache-validating conditional ('specific') or none ('unspecified'). In both cases, the revalidation occurs since `max-age` header is set to 0 by the browser.

A 'hard reload', on the other hand, seems to trigger an 'End-to-end reload' - no cached copies are allowed to be used. In this case, reload is forced by the browser setting `Pragma: no-cache`.