# Can't change styles using Site.css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC 4 and am using one of the tutorial projects I've found.  I'm at the point now where I'd like to play with styles, but am bewildered.  I thought changing a style in `site.css` would do the job, but no matter what I do it's ignored.  Here is the really weird part, though - when I delete the contents of `site.css` and run the project, everything looks like it did before I deleted the style code.  I realize that I don't yet fully understand specificity, but Firebug tells me that the styles are coming from `site.css`.

Can anyone tell me how this could be?

Comment: You use bundles or just loading Style.css directly?

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue.  When I develop website, I always set my browsers to always re-download content on each request (no caching), otherwise, I forget once and all hell breaks loose.

Comment: Try to run using Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Firebug will verify if your Site.css resource is cached -- check the network headers.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the CSS has been cached by the browser. What you can do if this is the issue is:

- Force reload all the resources by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.
- Try to open the site again in Incognito or Private Browsing window, close all the windows, and then open again in Incognito or Private Browsing window.

You can check the source of the `Site.css` file by opening the URL from the browser and verifying the contents. If the contents are old and not updated, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> on the `Site.css` page to find the updated file and then pressing just <kbd>F5</kbd> will display the updated styles.

Most common way to handle this in Visual Studio is:

- Clean Solution
- Build All

Answer (score 2):

The web browser download web pages and store them locally in your computer, in cache memory. When you visit the second time that page, the browser loading the page locally from cache and not downloading everything again.

Sometimes we need to manually delete the cache because the browser fails to recover the most recent copy available on the Site. I'll show you how to do it in 2 ways

1. Right-click on the refresh icon and choose the option "Hard Reload" or "Empty Change and Hard Reload".

[image]

2. In Google Chrome go to **History**(Ctrl+H) -> **Clear browsing data** -> and select **Changed images and files** -> press button **CLEAR DATA**

The difference between them can be found at this link:

[What's the difference between "Normal Reload", "Hard Reload", and "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a)