# Does "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" empty the entire cache or just parts relevant to the current site?

Tags: reload, chromium, http-caching

Does "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in Chromium/Chrome empty the entire cache or just parts relevant to the current site?

My inkling is that it empties absolutely all cached resources (as suggested in the comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969509/47773)).

However, a definitive answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It empties the entire cache.

You can verify this with these steps:

- Browse through a few sites ([reddit](http://www.reddit.com/), [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), ...)
- Enter `chrome://cache` into the omnibox
- Save the list of files
- Go to a basic website with no external resources like [example.com](http://www.example.com/)
- Open the developer console, right click on Refresh, and select *Empty Cache and Hard Reload*
- Enter `chrome://cache` into the omnibox again
- Compare the list of cached files with the list you saved in the third step. Files that were cached by Reddit and Stack Overflow will be gone, even though they are not referenced by example.com.

Answer (score 2):

It removes all cache. Hard reload would be like a hard reboot on a computer.