# Find a css file node js

Tags: node.js, file, express

Hi I'm new to nodejs and I've just succeed to deploy a nodejs app online. Now I would like to know how to link CSS, JS or image files be cause when I try to do it like I used to, I get the error `GET (not found)`.

The folder architecture is:

```
--public
    --assets
    --css
       index.css
    --js
--views
    --index.ejs
--node modules
app.js
package.json
```

Assuming that I want to code the link `index.css` in `index.ejs`, what I need to write in my `app.js` file please.

app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});


app.listen(8080,'IP_ADRESS');
```

index.ejs code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
```

Comment: You should add the css in the html file and set your express.static folder to "public". Show us your app.js so we could help you.

Comment: Is it more clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's a thing called a *static file*. Basically, that's a file that's sent over the internet without any kind of modification. Image and CSS files are typically static files.

It looks like you've put your static files in a folder called `public`.

Express has a built-in feature for sending static files, called `express.static`. You can use it like this:

```
// Require the modules we need.
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

// Create an Express app.
var app = express();

// Get the path to the `public` folder.
// __dirname is the folder that `app.js` is in.
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');

// Serve this path with the Express static file middleware.
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

// ...
```

You should now be able to see static files. If your site is normally accessible at `http://localhost:3000`, you'll be able to see `index.css` at `http://localhost:3000/css/index.css`.

If you want to know *way too much* about `express.static`, you can check out [a blog post I wrote](http://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/) that goes into Express's static files in depth.

Comment: Your code seems to sork when I inspect the Sources on google chrome I can see a index.css file, when I edit it, it edit my code, but when I try to edit the index.css file located on my server, there is not update. Thank you for your link, it appreciated

Comment: It's possible that your browser is caching `index.css`. Try doing [a hard reload](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14969315/804100) in your browser.

Comment: Do you have any cache middleware elsewhere in your Express app? Posting your `app.js` (or equivalent) would be useful.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just saw you updated your question. Are you sure you're updating the `index.css` that's on your file system?

Comment: It didn't realy work, But I found some bugs in my app, I think I'm not using express well so I restarted from the beginning and I try express generator.

Answer (score 1):

The basic set up of serving static files in express :

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
...
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
...
app.listen(3000);
```

Now in your .ejs in order to load the css styles or js scripts :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css"/>
```

Comment: This is correct for Express 2.x. This has changed in Express 3+.

Comment: I'm using Express 3+