# Remove memory cache in chrome devTools

Tags: performance, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

All data uri resources are coming as **(from memory cache)** under **Size** column in devtools. Even after i cleared **browsing data** of chrome and checked '**disable cache**' , and run in **private window** also,  its still coming as memory cache .

How to clear this memory cache and load fresh as first time.

Comment: Do you have a URL where I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Reproduce:http://www.brothercake.com/reference/datagen/demo.php

Comment: Thanks, I can repro. Investigating now...

Comment: See update in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47763263/1669860).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: Some DevTools engineers checked it out. DevTools lists Data URIs as originating from memory cache, even on a brand new Chrome profile. So it's a bug.

Try these:

- [Clear Storage pane](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage#clear-storage)
- [Empty Cache and Hard Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a)

Comment: Yes I tried clearing Application tab, all storage data and hard reload as you told the steps but it didnt work out

Comment: Hey! It's the guy from whats new in dev tools!

Comment: It is I, what's new in devtools guy

Comment: 9 months later, still present. Any ETA on a fix?

Comment: Neither of these solutions are working for me. Clearing storage, emptying the cache, hard reload, disabling cache, incognito browser. I even shut down my dev server and the images were still there, if that matters.

Comment: Do you have a link to the chrome bug? It's still present

Comment: Yeah it's still present. What is the solution to this? Anyone?

Comment: I cannot do the second suggestion because I am debugging a phone.  However, the first step is still not working for me