# Web page source seems to link to a different CSS stylesheet

Tags: css

I've uploaded all my html pages, css and supporting files to Bluehost.  Everything works locally - I know this is no guarantee it will work once it gets on the server.  The CSS file (which is in the same directory as index.html) successfully uploads to the server (I've checked to make sure it's the same) but, when I visit the page on the web it displays incorrectly.  I "view page source" and then click on the link to the .css near the top of the page.  When it displays it shows what appears to be the old .css.  There is no other .css file in the public_html folder.  The web page links to this .css

```
/*
    tswnavbar.css   1.2.1
    Please use the Navigation Menu Wizard at

    to generate your own customized menu buttons.
*/

#tswcssbuttons {
    width: 140px ;
    text-align: center ;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#tswcssbuttons ul {
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0 ;
list-style: none ;
}
#tswcssbuttons li {
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0 ;
    display: block ;
    list-style: none ;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
}
#tswcssbuttons li a {
    color: #000000 ;
    background-color: #667669 ;
    border: 1px outset #000000 ;
    text-decoration: none ;
    display: block ;
}
#tswcssbuttons li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff ;
    background-color: #000000 ;
}
```

However both my local copy and the uploaded copy have this additional code at the bottom but it's not showing up in the linked copy.

```
#social-media { 
    float: right ; 
}
#social-media ul li { 
    display: inline ; 
}
#social-media ul { 
    padding-top: 10px ; 
}
```

The formatting in the file is as it appears here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an issue relating to cache. Try clearing your browsers cache and trying to reload the page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The browser cache is a mechanism used by browsers to store locally web page resources. This adds performance gains, minimises bandwidth consumption and overall creates a snappier experience. In this article, we explain how browser caching works and how to implement it on your website. ([Source](https://pressidium.com/blog/2017/browser-cache-work/))

Sounds like your issue relates to browser cache. Your browser will generally cache web page resources, such as images, videos, CSS, JS and others. So that it doesn't have to re-download the page again if you access it again.

The simple solution is to [empty cache and hard reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969509/5030092).

Comment: Lachie - you're right.  I thought I had emptied the cache but obviously didn't.  Once I did everything worked fine.  Thanks much!

Comment: @RErik no worries, accept the answer using the tick if it worked!