# When I upload new web files to my hosting, my browser is returning the old CSS file

Tags: html, css, caching, browser

I'll upload my html, css, and javascript to my hosting; everyhthing works great. But then say I make a change locally to my CSS, i'll upload the CSS file again, redirect to my site but my site is still using the old CSS.

I can't seem to fix it unless I chnage the filename of my CSS. Is there a way to clear my browser from thinking it can just reuse the old css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on maciOS using chrome I found pressing `SHIFT + REFRESH` hard refreshes the page and forces re-downloading of all source files and images.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

That usually does it for me when that does it.

If not you can go into your browser's settings and remove the cached files for that website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a

Answer (score 1):

You can go in top menu:

**Firefox:** History > Clear Recent History

**Chrome:** History > Show full history > Clear browsing data

**Safari:** History > Clear history

**Internet Explorer:** Tools > Safety > Delete browsing history…

Or there are some additional plugins/addons to clear history for each browser.