# Detect a hard reload with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, reload

**For clarification:** I am **not** trying to differentiate between a refresh and a reload, hence this is not a duplicate of [refresh vs reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript). I am trying to find out if there is a way to detect when a user triggers a [*hard* reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969509/981933) instead of a normal reload. I am asking because I want to execute some code prior to a *hard* reload only.

---

Using JavaScript, via the browsers' reload button, or by a shortcut like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> it is possible to perform a **hard** reload of a browser tab. Is it possible to detect such a **hard** reload with JavaScript and if so how?

I know one can detect when a normal reload event is triggered with the `onbeforeunload` event and I can find out the navigation type to differentiate between a refresh and a reload but I am unable to detect a hard reload.

So far I'am using the following JS code to detect a reload:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';

  // For older browsers
  console.log('Is reloading?', event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type === 1);

  // For modern browsers
  const perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

  for (let i = 0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
    console.log('Is reloading? ', perfEntries[i].type === 1);
  }
});
```

I would like to be able to distinguish between a normal reload, e.g., `location.reload()`, and a forced reload, e.g., [`location.reload(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

Comment: Do you consider closing the browser and reopening it the same as a page refresh?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Ultimately you really can't tell what a browser is up to.

Comment: If the server sets a hash code as a cookie when the page is fetched, then the JS checks this hash code against local storage. If they do not match, then it was loaded but if they match it was cached. This works even if you use HTTP header caching.

Comment: @cgTag this is the most viable solution for me too

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar this is not a duplicate as the user are asking for a hard refresh vs refresh distinction

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini yeah, this is a server problem masquerading as a client problem. It's been asked many times on this website, but people keep wanting to solve the problem in JavaScript. It's the same as server programmers wanting to know what timezone a visitor is in by looking at their IP address, when it's a client side problem.

Comment: @cgTag Nope, it's not a server problem. Maybe I wasn't clear but I am simply trying to find out if there's a way to detect a specific browser event (a _hard reload_) is triggered. Other events like URL changes, clicks, idling, unloads, etc are also detectable so maybe there's a clever way to detect a **hard** reload as well (e.g., service workers might work).

Comment: There is no fool proof way to detect it

Comment: I don't know what the use case was for the OP, but I ran into one that could use this: XHR fetches that are returning stale cached content.  A hard refresh loads current content, but it doesn't load the same urls that are used with xhr, so they don't get purged from cache.  It would be nice to be able to take a hard refresh done by the user as a signal to send aggressive anti-chache headers with any following XHRs.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot detect hard refresh in javascript**, as there is no access to the headers for the currently loaded page.

The problem with J**avaScript is that it has no notion of a 304**. It begins executing in the context of a webpage, but it doesn't know how either itself or the page got there.

However, the server can tell from the request headers if this is a hard refresh, so there's the option of cooperating. For example the server can include a custom `<meta>` tag in the response or add a special class to `<body>` and your script will then have access to this information.

Another option is to **intercept key combination based on Browser/OS** and act before a hard refresh is triggered (appending something to the url, setting a cookie or a local/sessionstorage property)

Comment: Well there *is* the `PerformanceNavigationTiming` API, in some browsers.

Comment: Safari and Safari mobile does not support it at all and the only types contemplated are "navigate", "reload", "back_forward" or "prerender".

Comment: Yes I agree, it's just a new facility that makes it possible for a page to know *something* about how it was loaded. I personally am not sure what a normal application would do with that information.

Comment: "Safari and Safari mobile does not support it at all" but they support PerformanceNavigation. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation or test it yourself `console.log('Is reloading?', window.performance.navigation.type === 1);`. Hence, "it doesn't know how either itself or the page got there" is not entirely true.

Comment: @FLekschas it is not able to say whether is a refresh or hard refresh or not. So you do not know HOW EXACTLY you get there. It's a fact.